# xsl:number in child node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have XML which looks like this:

```
<A></A>
<A></A>
<A>
    <a/>
    <a/>
</A>
```

As you can see it has two levels `<A>` and `<a>`.

I wrote XSL tranform that generates index number on every `<A>` element and it works:

```
<xsl:template match "A">
<xsl:element name="Person">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:number count="A"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl>
```

Output:

```
<Person id="1"/>
<Person id="2"/>
<Person id="3"/>
```

But how to write xsl:number to generate the same number at `<a>` level (at `???`)?

```
<xsl:template match "A">
<xsl:element name="Person">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:number count="A"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl>
<xsl:template match "a">
<xsl:element name="Item">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:number count="???"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl>
```

Expected output (I want the same `id` for `<Person>` and `<Item>`):

```
<Person id="1"/>
<Person id="2"/>
<Person id="3">
   <Item id="3"/>
   <Item id="3"/>
</Person>
```

I know this must be some simple XPATH expression, but I really got stucked on this.

Comment: :-o would you please provide a desired output?

Comment: @rekaszeru: you're right. I've edited my question.

Comment: why do you want `Item id`'s that are not unique? If they are supposed to be references to the parent `Person`, why not say `<Item personRef="3"/>` or something like that? I guess this is just a matter of attribute naming, but it is confusing. E.g. @Alejandro generated different output because he thought you wanted the `Item` elements to have their own ID's.

Comment: @LarsH: well, right, the `id' was supposed to be the same for all items related to the same person. Sorry if my question was misleading. Actually, I was looking for a solution that was in Martin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your request to do it without passing a variable, see below.
The drawback is that `<xsl:number>` can't be used directly in an Attribute Value Template (as @Martin used the `$id` variable), so generating the `id` attribute becomes verbose.

```
<xsl:template match="A">
  <Person>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:number count="A" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a" />
  </Person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <Item>
    <xsl:attribute name="id"> <!-- I would name it personRef or something -->
      <xsl:number count="A" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </Item>
</xsl:template>
```

(Untested.)
The key here is using `select=".."` on `xsl:number` in the `"a"` template. **Edit:** It turns out that the `select=".."` is not actually necessary. Since the context node `a` does not match the count pattern `A`, it starts from the nearest ancestor that does match it. What a web of useful defaults [this instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#numbering-based-on-position) has!

Comment: It works, although: xalan in Java prints: Compiler warnings:
  line 92: Illegal attribute 'select'.

Comment: @Lukas: ok. See my new edit: the select is not needed (tested in XSLT 2.0)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply pass the computed number down if you really want the same:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
  <xsl:variable name="id">
    <xsl:number count="A"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <Person id="{$id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a">
      <xsl:with-param name="pid" select="$id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </Person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:param name="pid"/>
  <Item id="{$pid}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 It seems that that's the only working solution for now. Thanks

Comment: +1. I was wondering if it was possible to get the output of `<xsl:number>` into a variable. Why not.

Comment: I'm not marking this as the final solution yet. Perhaps it is possible to do it without passing variable?

Comment: @Lukas, yes, I will post in a separate answer.

Comment: @LarsH: I found the answer on my own. It's posted separately and very easy.

Comment: @Lukas Baran: I don't think that counting twice is going to have better performance than this.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have the answer. However I marked Lars' answer as the solution.

```
<xsl:template match "A">
<xsl:element name="Person">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:number count="A"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl>
<xsl:template match "a">
<xsl:element name="Item">
<xsl:attribute name="id">
<xsl:number count="A" level="any"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl>
```

It was enough to add `level="any"` attribute.

Comment: @LarsH - It does? It's not even well-formed XML.

Comment: I don't think the `level="any"` is needed. The `count="A"` should be sufficient. In XSLT 2.0 you can make the code a bit more compact by putting the `xsl:number` instruction inside a function, and calling it from within an AVT: `<Item id="my:number(.)">`

Comment: @lwburk: you're right, I was only responding to the use of `<xsl:number count="A" level="any" />` and omitting the passed parameter. Some of the non-wellformedness seems like just shorthand, but there are more serious problems like having a result element inside an attribute value. See my answer for a solution that does work.

Comment: @Michael, the `my:number(.)` in the `id` AVT needs to be in `{` curly braces `}`, right?

Comment: @Michael Kay: +1 That's an excellent comment. It has been a pain the missing of some kind of `numbering()` function.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! However I'm not using XSLT 2.0